# Cinnamon on Ubuntu high cpu usage

Tags: cinnamon

I am using the desktop environment Cinnamon on my 12.10 install. Everything works great, except that it uses an absurdly high amount of my cpu. My third core is always at +60%.

Any ideas?

Comment: Had the same experience. On a one core laptop. Not fun, but I couldn't find any solution. I ended up switching to XFCE.

Comment: @Linuxios That sucks. It's not a huge issue, but it is a little annoying because my cpu is a little warmer. Hopefully I find something.

Comment: On a 4 core system it is less of an issue, but on a one core AMD it was a deal breaker. XFCE was a lot nicer about resource usage.

Comment: "it uses an absurdly high amount of my cpu" ... What is "it"?

Comment: @vasa1 The cinnamon process.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same on 12.04 with cinnamon 1.6.7. All 4 cores (i5) were at ~50% constant with `strace` revealing intense polling activity (futex, poll, recvfrom). Mem usage was excessive too, nearing 2GB virt and ~250MB res.
Searching for cpu at [Cinnamon issues](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues) suggested it may be related to "***Cinnamon 2D***", which is what i was using.
Solved it by switching to "**Cinnamon**" (you have to logout for that), CPU now is below 4%.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, well are you running any  CPU hungry proccess? You can use the System Monitor to see if you are and you can edit what programs startup  using Startup Applications. other then that, it might just be Cinnamon itself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but now it's quiet calm :

```
hadi@hadi-MacBookPro:~$ sensors
applesmc-isa-0300
Adapter: ISA adapter
Left side  : 3082 RPM  (min = 2000 RPM)
Right side : 3081 RPM  (min = 2000 RPM)
TB0T:         +37.5°C  
TB1T:         +37.5°C  
TB2T:         +36.0°C  
TC0C:         +71.2°C  
TC0D:         +67.8°C  
TC0E:         +70.2°C  
TC0F:         +72.2°C  
TC0P:         +58.5°C  
TC1C:         +70.0°C  
TC2C:         +67.0°C  
TC3C:         +69.0°C  
TC4C:         +69.0°C  
TCFC:          +0.0°C  
TCGC:         +71.0°C  
TCSA:         +68.0°C  
TCTD:          +0.0°C  
TG0D:         +61.0°C  
TG0P:         +56.0°C  
THSP:         +48.0°C  
TM0S:         +62.2°C  
TMBS:          +0.0°C  
TP0P:         +62.2°C  
TPCD:         +66.0°C  
TW0P:        +129.0°C
```

I just removed the FGLRX driver proposed by the Additional Drivers utility and installed the latest one from AMD website.

I have Radeon 6400M ATI card and now running the 3.2.0-48-generic kernel on precise 12.04 LTS ubuntu